# STM32F030 I2C: Avoiding NACK

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, embedded, programming

I am trying to port my I2C code from STM32F103 to STM32F030. Everything works fine with writes (writes to an eeprom), but when I try to read from an EEPROM (first write transmission with memory address, and then a read transmission to read the data) I get a NACK when starting the read transmission.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
i2c1_transmission_start(0b1010000, I2C_WRITE, 2, 10000);
i2c1_transmission_write8(0);
i2c1_transmission_write8(0);
i2c1_transmission_stop();
i2c1_transmission_start(0b1010000, I2C_READ, 2, 60000);
i2c1_transmission_read8(&data1);
i2c1_transmission_end(I2C_READ);
data2 = I2C1->RXDR;
```

It works perfectly well on the STM32F103. But, after I ported my code STM32F030, it does not work: right after I start the read transmission, I get a NACK from my EEPROM (M24C02) and further read8 times out - RXNE is never set. I feel that I'm not waiting for something at the transmission end or start, but I don't not what am I not waiting for.

Sure, I can just wait some fixed time between the transmissions, but why does it work on F103 without any delay?

In further implementation, i2c1_waitBit just waits for a certain bit in SR (for f103, ISR for f030) with a timeout and returns an error if timeout occured.

Here is the implementation of said functions (transmission_start, write8, transmission_end) on F103:

```
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_start(uint8_t addr, _i2c_wrmode mode, uint16_t busy_timeout) {
    // Return if any error occurred earlier immediately, wait while I2C is busy
    if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}
    uint16_t tmo_busy = busy_timeout;
    while((((I2C1->SR2) & I2C_SR2_BUSY) == I2C_SR2_BUSY) && (tmo_busy > 0)) {tmo_busy--;}
    if(tmo_busy == 0) {_i2c1_error |= I2C_ERR_BUSY;}

    if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}
    // Enable ACK
    MODIFY_REG(I2C1->CR1, I2C_CR1_POS | I2C_CR1_ACK, I2C_CR1_ACK);

    // Send start condition
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
    WAITBITTMO(I2C1->SR1, I2C_SR1_SB, 10000);
    (void) I2C1->SR1;

    // Send address
    addr <<= 1; if(mode == I2C_READ) {addr |= 0b1;}
    MODIFY_REG(I2C1->DR, I2C_DR_DR, addr);
    RETERR(i2c1_waitBit(I2C_SR1_ADDR), _i2c1_error);
    (void) I2C1->SR1; (void) I2C1->SR2;
    return _i2c1_error;
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_end(_i2c_wrmode mode) {
    if(mode == I2C_WRITE) {
        uint16_t tmo = 1000;
        while(
            (((I2C1->SR1) & I2C_SR1_BTF) != I2C_SR1_BTF) &&
            (_i2c1_error == 0) &&
            (tmo > 0)
        ) {tmo--;};

        if(tmo == 0) {_i2c1_error |= I2C_ERR_TMO;}
        if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}

        // Send stop condition
        I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
        WAITNBIT(I2C1->SR1, I2C_SR1_STOPF);
    } else {
        I2C1->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_ACK;
        I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
        WAITNBIT(I2C1->SR1, I2C_SR1_STOPF);
        WAITBIT(I2C1->SR1, I2C_SR1_RXNE);
    }
    return _i2c1_error;
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_write8(uint8_t byte) {
    MODIFY_REG(I2C1->DR, I2C_DR_DR, byte);
    return i2c1_waitBit(I2C_SR1_TXE);
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_read8(uint8_t* byte) {
    RETERR(i2c1_waitBit(I2C_SR1_RXNE), _i2c1_error);
    *byte = I2C1->DR & I2C_DR_DR;
    return _i2c1_error;
}
```

Here is the implementation on F030:

```
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_start(uint8_t addr, _i2c_wrmode mode, uint8_t nBytes, uint16_t busy_timeout) {
    // Return if any error occurred earlier immediately, wait while I2C is busy
    if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}
    uint16_t tmo_busy = busy_timeout;
    while((((I2C1->ISR) & I2C_ISR_BUSY) == I2C_ISR_BUSY) && (tmo_busy > 0)) {tmo_busy--;}
    if(tmo_busy == 0) {_i2c1_error |= I2C_ERR_BUSY;}

    if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}

    // Send start condition
    I2C1->CR2 = (nBytes << 16) | (addr << 1) | I2C_CR2_START | (mode == I2C_READ ? I2C_CR2_RD_WRN : 0);
    i2c1_waitBit(I2C_ISR_TXE);
    return _i2c1_error;
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_end(_i2c_wrmode mode) {
    if(mode == I2C_WRITE) {
        uint16_t tmo = 1000;
        while(
            (((I2C1->ISR) & I2C_ISR_TC) != I2C_ISR_TC) &&
            (_i2c1_error == 0) &&
            (tmo > 0)
        ) {tmo--;};

        if(tmo == 0) {_i2c1_error |= I2C_ERR_TMO;}
        if(_i2c1_error != 0) {return _i2c1_error;}

        // Send stop condition
        I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_STOP;
        (void) I2C1->ISR;
        I2C1->ICR |= I2C_ICR_STOPCF;
    } else {
        I2C1->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_STOP;
        (void) I2C1->ISR;
        I2C1->ICR |= I2C_ICR_STOPCF;
        //WAITBIT(I2C1->ISR, I2C_ISR_RXNE);
    }
    return _i2c1_error;
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_write8(uint8_t byte) {
    I2C1->TXDR = byte;
    return i2c1_waitBit(I2C_ISR_TXE);
}
uint8_t i2c1_transmission_read8(uint8_t* byte) {
    RETERR(i2c1_waitBit(I2C_ISR_RXNE), _i2c1_error);
    *byte = I2C1->RXDR;
    return _i2c1_error;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NAK because you first write data 0 to address 0 and then you immediately want to read the result from some address but the EEPROM is busy writing so it will not acknowledge until internal write cycle is complete.

Comment: Nope, it's a two-byte-address EEPROM, so it's not writing data 0 to address 0, it's selecting a 16-bit address 0. It works without any delay on F103 with the same EEPROM.

Comment: @sx107 M24C02 is not a two-byte-address EEPROM.

Comment: oops. Written the original code for M24M01 and kind of forgotten that. Thank you!